# check discord bot dm's

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

so i'm new to discord bots and i wanted to make it so when someone dm's the bot the bot sends that dm to me

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith("$suggest"):
        await message.channel.send("check dm's", delete_after=5, reference=message)
        await message.author.send("please type $suggest (suggestion)")
    #if person dms me and content startswith $suggest:
        #send the dm to me or suggestions chat
```

Comment: You can say, for example, that this message should also be sent to `dev`. To explain it: `await dev.send(....)` and define yourself as `dev` beforehand with `dev = bot.get_user(UserID)`.

Comment: What's going wrong with this code then?

Answer (score 0):

You can check for DMChannels using `isinstance(message.channel, discord.DMChannel)` and then send a message to you using `me = bot.get_user(your_discord_id)` and then `me.send(f"Suggestion by {message.author}:\n{message.content}")`.

All of this in your code would be:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith("$suggest"):
        await message.channel.send("check dm's", delete_after=5, reference=message)
        await message.author.send("please type $suggest (suggestion)")
    if message.content.startswith("$suggest") and isinstance(message.channel, discord.DMChannel)
        me = bot.get_user(your_discord_id)
        me.send(f"Suggestion by {message.author}:\n{message.content}")
```

---

**References:**

- [Client.get_user(id)](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=get_user#discord.Client.get_user)